# Create pure Java HTTPS server with "single sided" authentication?

Tags: java, https

I can easily create a HTTP pure Java server that I need for my purposes. But, a HTTPS server like this:

```
package httpstest;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsConfigurator;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

public class HttpsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(createSSLContext()));
        server.createContext("/test", new TestHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }

    private static SSLContext createSSLContext() throws Exception {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("server.crt");
        InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        caInput.close();

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context;
    }

    static class TestHandler implements HttpHandler {

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String response = "Successfully connected!";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

will compile and run server-side with no errors but will yield an SSL error from the browser. It seems like the server is expecting the browser to have the same certificate. I want any browser to connect to it via HTTPS without an installed certificate (just like someone would connect to https://www.google.com)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Here is the key piece of code:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
char[] keystorePassword = "password".toCharArray();
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("filename.jks"), keystorePassword);
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, keystorePassword);
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
HttpsConfigurator configurator = new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are the server, you need to install your private cert in the `KeyManager`. The `TrustManager` is for public certs corresponding to private client certs. obviously, if you don't want a browser to complain, you need a private cert from a trusted CA.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to Google using HTTPS, the certificate is avaliable in your browser already, because it is a certificate signed by a trusted CA.

To do what you intend, you must use a signed certificate (you need to pay for that OR some people uses a free signed certificate from [StarCom](http://cert.startcom.org/), but I'm not sure about the last one)